# Create an autopath or a token using entity reference of entity reference

Tags: entities, tokens

I have created a new node type "station". This node type has an entity reference to another node type "location", which in turn has an entity reference to a node type "prefecture".

I would be interested to have an autopath for the station, which would be of the form
http://www.website.com/[prefecture:name]/[station:name]

The problem is that prefecture:name does not appear in the tokens for node 'station'. Any idea how to go further with this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that was easy. One has to enable the Entity Token module, which creates automatically nested tokens for all depths of entity references.